# "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" error when trying to save excel file with openpyxl in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a couple of excel files I want to merge into one.
I need the second column on all the files to be copied into separate columns in a new Microsoft Excel file.
For this, I am using the `openpyxl` library in a python script.

This is my code:

```py
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def mergeDataFiles():
    path = "C:\\Users\\ethan\\Desktop\\Benzoyl Chloride\\Benzoyl Chloride"
    # source excel files
    origin_files = list()
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file_index in range(len(files)):
            origin_files.append(files[file_index])
    # destination excel file
    destination_file = path + ".xlsx"
    destination_workbook = load_workbook(destination_file)
    destination_sheet = destination_workbook["Sheet1"]
    # copy data from source files to destination file
    for origin_file_index in range(1, len(origin_files)):
        origin_workbook = load_workbook(path + "\\" + origin_files[origin_file_index - 1])
        origin_sheet = origin_workbook['Data']
        destination_sheet.cell(row=1, column=origin_file_index).value = origin_files[origin_file_index - 1]
        for i in range(1, 500):
            # read cell value from source excel file
            data = origin_sheet.cell(row=i, column=2)
            # write the value to destination excel file
            destination_sheet.cell(row=i + 1, column=origin_file_index).value = data.value

    # saving the destination excel file
destination_workbook.save(destination_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mergeDataFiles()
```

When I run the code, I get an error on the last line in the function: `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`.

Full traceback:

```
C:\Users\ethan\.venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/ethan/Coding/Python/Copy Excel Data/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ethan\Coding\Python\Copy Excel Data\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    mergeDataFiles()
  File "C:\Users\ethan\Coding\Python\Copy Excel Data\main.py", line 28, in mergeDataFiles
    destination_workbook.save(destination_file)
  File "C:\Users\ethan\.venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 407, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\ethan\.venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\ethan\.venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\ethan\.venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 67, in write_data
    archive.writestr(ARC_APP, tostring(props.to_tree()))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1830, in writestr
    with self.open(zinfo, mode='w') as dest:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1204, in close
    self._fileobj.seek(self._zinfo.header_offset)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Exception ignored in: <function ZipFile.__del__ at 0x000001D101443D80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1870, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1892, in close
    self._fpclose(fp)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1992, in _fpclose
    fp.close()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried changing the file names and locations, having the destination file open and closed, scouring the internet for solutions and at this point I'm not sure what else I can try.
I am running the code on Windows 10 22H2, with an intel i5 cpu.

Please assist me with this issue, if you know how to solve it.

Comment: Alright, I'll add it in a sec.

Comment: Have you tried saving to a different file path? Excel files cannot be saved if they are open anywhere else, and it may still be opened by your script. `destination_workbook.save()` may be sufficient if that's the case.

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: `for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):` is overwriting your `path` variable on each iteration. Change it to something like `for _, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):` since you aren't using it anyway.